# Alter tick labels to a '10^ - style' appearance

Tags: matlab, axis-labels

Though there are quite a lot of answered questions to that kind of issue, I wasn’t able to find a proper solution for my exact problem. Anyway.

I try to format my tick lables like shown in the following example:

[image]

I already found out that the ‘sprintf’ command is offering a possibility to alter the tick format. The closest I came to what I want is the 'e-notation' triggered by the following command:

```
set(ax,'YTickLabel',sprintf('%2.0e|',yticks))
```

However, I’d like my labels to appear just as shown in the example picture. Is there a simple way to do that?

Thank you very much in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something? Why not use `semilogy`?

```
x = -3:0;
y = 10.^x;
semilogy(x, y);
set(gca, 'YMinorGrid', 'on')
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Latex formatting and [sprintfc](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) to produce what you want. (You might not need `sprintfc` at all actually but that's a nice way of creating a cell array of strings with numbers in a single line.):

```
set(ax,'YTickLabels',sprintfc('10^{%i}',yticks)
```

In a general example (here with x-axis formatted):

```
clear
clc
close all

x = 0:100000;
y = log(x);

figure
semilogx(x,y)

xt = get(gca,'XTick');

set(gca,'XTickLabels',sprintfc('10^{%i}',0:numel(xt)-1))
```

outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Benoit for your fast answer. Unfortunately the exponent in my case is plotted in curly brackets and is not supersrcipted.

[link](http://imgur.com/iJs5GqF)

Comment: Oh shoot. What if you specify the interpreter as being latex?